# Maximum execution time of 300 seconds Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 17087648: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Array
(
    [type] => 1
    [message] => Maximum execution time of 300 seconds e' at line 163
```

При вливе базы данных вылазит ошибка.
Посмотрел нашел как править похожие ошибки для выполнения php скриптов.(в `php.ini` на всяк случай увеличил лимит)

Как можно увеличить время выполнения скрипта для влива дампа?

Делаю влив через консоль*

Comment: вижу что пишут нжно $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] прописать нужно значение, но куда его лепить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Пройдите к файлу по адресу:
>
> ```
> \phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php
> ```
>
> Меняйте значение
>
> ```
> $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 600;
> ```
>
> Меняйте на то значение, которое исправит ошибку.

[Ссылка на оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13858161/980828)

На Ubuntu 14.04 смотреть по адресу:

```
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php
```

Comment: там написано для винды, такой путь я могу найти на ubunte по пути /var/lib/phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php но он пустой, мне туда ето нужно вставить?

Comment: Просто не могу найти ни в одном файе $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 600;

Comment: Делаю влив через консоль*

Answer (score 1):

[Не нужно решать задачи не теми средствами](http://habrahabr.ru/post/179399/).

Вариант 1. Используйте [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Вариант 2. Используйте [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html).

Не используйте PHP для больших файлов, в конце-то концов.

Я бы еще глянул на ту самую строку 17087648 - может вполне быть проблема не со временем, а с данными:

> уou have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: Автор не написал сам, но проблема была в phpmyadmin. Я добавил нужный тег.

Comment: Так консоль, которая была упомянута в комментариях - это phpmyadmin?

Comment: Похоже на то :)

Comment: Вобщем что произошло - я использовал для создания дампа phpmyadmin и так как база 9гб он оборал влив. Потом я через консоль ету неполную базу раза 3 пытаюсь влить через mysqldum -u -p < some.sql и оно выбивает такие ошибки. Короче щас делаю сам дамп через консоль, и сделаю по новой влив

Comment: PS что оборвало я не видел)))